# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I submit my form with jQuery:

```
$('#saveButton').click(function () {                
                if (true) {
                    $('#submitForm').submit();
                } 
            });
```

I get an error in the file `jquery....min.js`:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

I'm using asp.net MVC to generate the form:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
```

Submit Buttons.  I am using the top one.  The button one is not clicked when this happens:

```
<input type="button" id="saveButton" class="bigButton" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" id="submitRequestButton" class="bigButton" value="Submit" />
```

I look in the network tab on FF and I don't see a POST.  How can I track down or narrow down what is causing this problem?

**Update**

The code in the console window is all I get and its pointing me to the minified jQuery lib:

/*! jQuery v2.1.0 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
!function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0):function(a){if(!a.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return b(a)}:b(a)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(a,b){var c=[],d=c.slice,e=c.concat,f=c.push,g=c.indexOf,h={},i=h.toString,j=h.hasOwnProperty,k="".trim,l={},m=a.document,n="2.1.0",o=function(a,b){return new o.fn.init(a,b)},p=/^-ms-/,q=/-([\da-z])/gi,r=function(a,b){return b.toUpperCase()};o.fn=o.prototype={jquery:n,constructor:o,selector:"",length:0,toArray:function(){return

...and this goes on for about 1000 more lines or so.

Comment: Can you post the json data or sample of it?

Comment: Did you see the console for javascript error?

Comment: I don't see any JSON data and I have no idea how I can obtain it without the POST information in the Network tab.  The console info is gibberish to me, I posted a short sample.

Comment: can you show you complete view with jquery include code?

Comment: Is your submit button part of the form? Had this problem myself a couple of days ago.

Comment: Wondering how come a firefox-FireBug console tab shows a entire jQuery library code :)

Comment: @NicklasWinger - Yes, the question is updated with that info.  Ehsan - Sorry the full view is way too big to post here.

Comment: Ok. Another sunn question; you do have actual controller and action names in the helper, right? :)

Comment: @NicklasWinger Yea, these were working up until recently.  The changes I've made have been mostly JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by removing the MVC validation scripts and my own custom validation scripts from the code:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/conditional-validation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/customItemRequestValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I wrote new custom validation that is not based on MVC's validation.  I have no need for MVC's built in validation.  I don't know why one of these files is causing a JSON parse error.

The old custom validation scripts that I removed did stuff like:

`$.validator.addMethod('requiredif',`

and

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    'requiredif',
```

My guess is one of my old custom validation scripts was messed up or my new validation scripts conflict with MVC's validation scripts somehow.

Comment: i think these validation codes from different place conflict.